# react native image type .jfif support

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image

I am doing a login with Facebook in the app. where I get a user profile pic. Facebook SDK returns a profile pic URL.

[profile pic](https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=944646413029075&height=50&width=50&ext=1617003623&hash=AeS_ezW7XV1tQCgY4og)

I have saved this file in  directory `assets/download.jfif`
and I get it in the `RegisterScreen.js` like this

```
<Image
 onError={() => console.log('Error')}
 onLoad={() => console.log('On Load')}
 onLoadStart={() => console.log("onLoadStart")}
 onLoadEnd={() => console.log('onLoadEnd')}
 style={{width:normalize(35), height:normalize(35)}}
 source={require('../assets/download.jfif')}
/>
```

but this gives me an error

```
`[Error: undefined Unable to resolve module `../assets/download.jfif` from src\screens\RegisterScreen.js`:`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue, but with a remote image. It seems like RN does not support ".JFIF" images. If it's a static image You can try to convert it to another supported format. As liste here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#source

As of the time of writing:

> The currently supported formats are png, jpg, jpeg, bmp, gif, webp,
> psd (iOS only). In